Datastage: loading csv file with timestamp with nanoseconds using schema file
I'm trying to load csv file with timestamp value like 2024-07-01 08:01:43.921000000 using schema file in Datastage.
I tried in schema file like below but it didn't work:

ZEITSTEMPEL_LETZT_GELOG_ANGEB:nullable timestamp { timestamp_format='%yyyy-%mm-%dd %hh:%nn:%ss.%SSSSSSSSS', null_field='' };
ZEITSTEMPEL_LETZT_GELOG_ANGEB:nullable timestamp { timestamp_format='%yyyy-%mm-%dd %hh:%nn:%ss.9', null_field='' };

result was:
(SF_READ_FILE: Error when checking operator: At field "ZEITSTEMPEL_LETZT_GELOG_ANGEB": When validating import/export function: "timestamp_format" property value (%yyyy-%mm-%dd %hh:%nn:%ss.%SSSSSSSSS) is not a valid format.).:
Can anyone please help me with that?
